# Validate specific string pattern in Java

Tags: java

I want to validate pattern of input string as two numbers then three capital alphabet then three numbers.

For example: "16FIT146" string should be valid.

Comment: This is what is sometimes called a "gimme teh codez" question. On Stack Overflow, we ask that question authors make an effort on their problem to start with, ask a question, **and show their work**. This is particularly the case on regular expressions, SQL, XPath and other short string-based questions where helpers could be kept busy all day in response to zero-effort queries.

Comment: Although we understand that this approach is more work, we think it is a good use of the time of the question authors, since (a) they will learn something, and (b) they will only ask questions that are important to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using regular expressions

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String patternStr = "\\d{2}\\w{3}\\d{3}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

        String input = "16FIT146";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        if (!matcher.matches()) {//invalid input
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        } else {//valid input
            System.out.println("Valid");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could this regex

```
String pattern = "^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$";

if (str.matches(pattern)) {
  // something here.
}
```

Example

```
 public static void main(String []args){
   matches("16FIT146");
   matches("anything");
 }

 public static void matches(String str) {
    String pattern = "^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}$";
    if (str.matches(pattern)) {
        System.out.println("matches");
    } else {
        System.out.println("not matches");
    }
 }
```